# CSS / IE - Remove the dotted lines when select something in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Whenever I select an element in Internet Explorer, dotted lines appear around it, almost like a border. Is there anyway to disable this?

Comment: What do you mean by "select"? Are you selecting a form element, or text, or a DOM element using the developer tools, or something else?

Comment: Try `*:focus { outline: 0 !important; }` but if it works, it'd only work in IE8+.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your css:

```
a {
  outline: none;
  border: none; /* eventually, IE specific, not sure */
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'Eventually'? Why haven't you included `border:none` in your code?

Comment: Ahh ofcourse! outline, cheers that solved it!

Comment: @curt because I am not sure if IE needs border: none; or if it works without. I have included it in my answer, but because you ask **so politely**, i will add it into the code part, just for you.

Answer (score 2):

> Blockquote Try *:focus { outline: 0 !important; } but if it works, it'd only work in IE8+.

This will delete borders around inputs if you apply to all (*).  So make sure you also declare  a border for inputs and textareas.